# Why does RhinoMocks behave differently in VB & C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net, unit-testing, rhino-mocks, rhino-mocks-3.5

I have test code similar to this:

```
Public Interface IDoSomething
   Function DoSomething(index As Integer) As Integer
End Interface

<Test()>
Public Sub ShouldDoSomething()
   Dim myMock As IDoSomething = MockRepository.GenerateMock(Of IDoSomething)()

   myMock.Stub(Function(d) d.DoSomething(Arg(Of Integer).Is.Anything))
      .WhenCalled(Function(invocation) invocation.ReturnValue = 99)
      .Return(Integer.MinValue)

   Dim result As Integer = myMock.DoSomething(808)

End Sub
```

This code doesn't behave as expected though. The variable `result` contains `Integer.MinValue` not 99, as expected.

If I write the equivalent code in C# it works as anticipated: `result` contains 99.

Any ideas why?

C# equivalent:

```
public interface IDoSomething
{
   int DoSomething(int index)
}

[test()]
public void ShouldDoSomething()
{
   var myMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IDoSomething>();

   myMock.Stub(d => d.DoSomething(Arg<int>.Is.Anything))
      .WhenCalled(invocation => invocation.ReturnValue = 99)
      .Return(int.MinValue);

   var result = myMock.DoSomething(808);
}
```

Comment: You should provide the C# code as well. What you consider to be equivalent might not be so, and might be where the answer lies.

Comment: Huh, why are you providing two different return values? Can't you drop the `WhenCalled()` and just use `Return()`? No idea on the reason for diverging behavior though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference will be `Function(invocation) invocation.ReturnValue = 99` is an inline function returning a `Boolean`, where as `invocation => invocation.ReturnValue = 99` is an inline function returning `99` and setting `invocation.ReturnValue` to `99`.

If you're using a late enough version of VB.NET you can use `Sub(invocation) invocation.ReturnValue = 99` unless `WhenCalled` expects a return value.